# How to increase nginx connections

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, tcp

I am facing the problem of nginx max connection issues.
I am not able to increase max active connections(520) made by nginx.
Some time it is using whole writing (516) operation connections. and due to this other requests are all pending.

Does anybody know how to increase nginx active max connections.

Using CentOS release 5.8 (Final)

NGINX status:

> Active connections: 519
>   server accepts handled requests
>   4693 4693 1276317
>   Reading: 2 Writing: 1 Waiting: 516

NGINX conf file:

```
user nginx root;
worker_processes  16;
worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;
#worker_connections  10240;


error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  10240;
    use epoll;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
      index index.php index.htm index.html;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    access_log off;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     on;
    server_tokens   off;
    gzip            on;
    gzip_static     on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    keepalive_timeout  30;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    limit_conn_zone   $binary_remote_addr  zone=addr:10m;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        limit_conn addr 20000;
        listen       7007;
        server_name  _;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        location / {
#            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
#            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;

        location = /404.html {
#            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
      location /favicon.ico {
          empty_gif;
      }
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
#            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
#            root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
            #fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            #include        fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_send_timeout  8m;
          fastcgi_read_timeout 8m;
          fastcgi_connect_timeout 8m;
          #uwsgi_pass_request_body off;
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        }

      location /status {
            stub_status on;
              access_log   off;
         }
   }
}
```

Also I have set these information too for increasing max connection

```
cat  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
9000    65535

cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait 
1
```

But thease setting are not working.

If you need any other information please notify me.

Thanks

Comment: do you get anything in the logfiles, indicationg xxx_limits reached or so? i think of /etc/security/limits.conf. we had a similar issue for a static-server under fire where we had to adjust and increase the limits

Comment: We have already increase the ulimit according to http://www.eddieoneverything.com/linux/linux-whm-cpanel-resource-temporarily-unavailable.php as we are using whm.

But the limit of max active connection has not been increase from 520. And I didn't see anything in var/log/messages log of limits reached.

Could you please tell us is there any other way to increase limit of nginx?

Comment: you should ask this question on the [nginx-forum](http://forum.nginx.org)

Comment: btw, is this a centos-version or a selfcompiled version of nginx?

Comment: It is compiled version from the source code.

Comment: oih, and can you please reedit your question and adjust the formatiting of your nginx.conf? quite hard to read :)

Comment: Can it limited on your fastcgi_process side?

Comment: There is an extensive list of parameters to look at on this nginx page: [http://nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/](http://nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/).  Note that sometimes on VM's, not real servers, the parameters you change are actually limited by the host.